# Put in URL an mysql_fetch_array item

Tags: php

I have a mysql table I want to echo the name of every user and on click on a certain user show his profile:

```
$user=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM signup ORDER BY name ASC ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user)){

echo '<a href="profil.php?user='."$row[".username."]".'">'.$row['nume'].' '.$row['prenume']."</a>";

echo "<br>";}
```

The problem is that i can not figure out how to concatenate $row['username'] with href

The output should look like this: www.abcde.de/profil?user=username

Comment: what output you need please specify it first

Comment: `echo '<a href="profil.php?user='.$row['username'].'">'.$row['nume'].' '.$row['prenume'].'</a>';` - to many mixed `'` and `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  echo '<a href="profil.php?user='.$row['username'].'">'.$row['nume'].' '.$row['prenume'].'</a>';
```

Comment: That is still not right. Where does `.username.` come from? A fieldname in a table?